# iOS - Xcode - OpenCV - findContours error

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, opencv, contour

`findContours` causes the following error:

> 2017-09-22 16:50:05.396700+0200 OpenCVLiveCamera[7827:3041522] [MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is /private/var/containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
>   2017-09-22 16:50:05.397011+0200 OpenCVLiveCamera[7827:3041522] [MC] Reading from public effective user settings.
>   OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (mtype == type0 || (CV_MAT_CN(mtype) == CV_MAT_CN(type0) && ((1 << type0) & fixedDepthMask) != 0)) in create, file /Volumes/build-storage/build/master_iOS-mac/opencv/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp, line 2601
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type cv::Exception: /Volumes/build-storage/build/master_iOS-mac/opencv/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp:2601: error: (-215) mtype == type0 || (CV_MAT_CN(mtype) == CV_MAT_CN(type0) && ((1 << type0) & fixedDepthMask) != 0) in function create

Code:

```
void getContours(cv::Mat &srcImage){
    cv::Mat dstImage = srcImage;
    // Convert it to gray
    cvtColor( srcImage, srcImage, CV_BGR2GRAY );
    // Threshold
    threshold(srcImage, srcImage, 192.0, 255.0, cv::THRESH_BINARY_INV);
    // Find Contours to find chains of consecutive edge pixels
    std::vector<std::vector<Point> > contours;
    findContours(srcImage, contours, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);
    // Draw contours on image
    //....
}
```

please help.
Thank you

Comment: Post your image.

Comment: iPhone camera image of a hand.

Comment: It’s likely the image didn’t load. You should post that part also.

Comment: The image loads fine because when I comment out the line with findContours, the black and white thresholded image of the hand is displayed in live.

Answer (score 2):

Solved by changing `Point` to `cv::Point` in

```
 std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > contours;
```

Answer (score 0):

`findContours` changes the input image so it can’t be displayed. Try

```
threshImg = srcImg.clone()
findContours(threshImg, contours, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);
```

Comment: The problem is not that I cannot display the changed image; the program exits with an error as soon as it hits findContours before trying to display the image.